# Modify Character or Word after typing it JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, textarea

Lets say I am typing the word "hello" into a textarea. How would I, after I had typed hello, select that word I had just typed, and modify it. For example, after I typed the word hello, without hitting the space bar, recognize the word is hello, and before and after it add `<b>` and `</b>` around the word. So the ending result would be `<b>hello</b>` I know textarea's don't take HTML, but for the sake of argument. The only way I can think to do this is to run a function each time the user presses a key, and add the content of the textarea to an array, breaking it at the spaces. But that requires spaces, and than having to cross reference the array will take time. Is there anyway to do this easily?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want functionality such that typing the letter `o` in the textarea with the text `I said hell` to change to `I said <b>hello</b>`?

Comment: yes. Exactly. but in a contenteditable div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll definitely have to trap each keypress if you want it to do the replacement as you type, but you don't have to test for spaces. The following worked when I tested it in IE:

```
$(function() {
   $("#yourtextareaidhere").keyup(function(e) {
      var updatedText = this.value.replace(
                               /(^|[^>])(hello)($|[^<])/gi, "$1<b>$2</b>$3");
      if (updatedText != this.value)
         this.value = updatedText;
   });
});
```

Essentially on every keypress this does a string replace to take all instances of "hello" not already surrounded by ">" and "<" (including where "hello" is at the start or end of the string), and substitute in `"<b>hello</b>"`. If the result of the string replace is different to what was in the field (i.e., some substitution did occur) then the new value is written back to the textarea - I don't just write it back directly every time because that loses the cursor position which is annoying for the user and I'm too lazy to come up with a better workaround than this simple "if" test. (I justify this on the basis that I'm providing you with a "starting place", and leaving the rest to you.)

This approach allows for the fact that the user may not have typed the word "hello" in one go, e.g., if they made a typo and initially had "I say hllo to you" then went back and added the "e" then you (presumably) want to replace the "hello" even though it isn't at the end. Also I do a global replace so that if the user pastes in "hello hello hello" they'll all be replaced. Decide for yourself if you want a case-insensitive replacement.

If there are other words you are looking to replace too you could add them to the same regular expression if they all just need the bold tags, otherwise if each special word has its own required formatting define an array of search regexes and replacement strings and loop through them within the function.

Note that my regular expressions are a bit rusty so I won't be at all surprised if there's a nicer way to do the same thing, but I'll leave any improvements as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Yes I don't quite understand you RegExp. Because I was using `<b>` as an example. It will probably end up being a `<span>` or a `<p>`

Comment: Also do you know anything about contenteditable divs? Because I wanna use this in one of those too, and it works great! but after it changes the text, it loses focus

Comment: If you want a `<span>` or `<p>` instead of `<b>` then (why didn't you say so in the question, and) just put them in instead of `<b>` in this string from my code: `"$1<b>$2</b>$3"`. As for how the RegEx works, there lots of tutorials that I'm sure you can find with Google, or have a look at [what MDN says about Regex in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) - take note of "capturing parentheses" for what the `$1` syntax means in the replacement string. I've done little with editable divs, but my answer already mentions leaving the focus problem to you...

Comment: It works fine in the textarea, but in the editable div, it acts really weird. REALLY WEIRD.

Comment: Sorry, I've rarely touched editable divs so I don't know what the problem might be. I believe I've given a reasonable answer to the question as originally asked, so to get further help with your editable div focus issue you should post another question (or update this one).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [JQuery.keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) function to listen for the space key press.

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(event)
{ 
    var c= String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    var isWhiteSpace = c.match(/\s/);
});
```

You can use the [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and [join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) function as well to accomplish what you describe in the latter part of your question.

Edit: Here's more on this idea: http://jsfiddle.net/ingenu8/ukkwM/

```
<div class="formatted"></div>
<textarea class="observed"></textarea>
```

and the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function hasHtml(str)
    {
        return str.match(/<b>.*?<\/b>/);
    }

    function formatStr(str)
    {
        var bits = str.split(/\s+/);
        var last = bits.pop();
        if(!last.match(/^\s*$/))
        {
            if(!hasHtml(last))
            {
                bits.push('<b>'+last+'</b>');
            }
        }
        return bits.join(' ');
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        var str = formatStr($('.observed').val());
        $('.formatted').html(str);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I unerstand what you are saying but this doesn't answer my questions. I know how to listen for space presses, but thats what I am trying to avoid. I want to be able to have the string recognized before the spacebar even has to be hit

Comment: @JonahAllibone You can use setInterval to execute a function and act as an observer on a field. You can keep track of the length of the field as a way of checking whether you should format the string.

Comment: @JonahAllibone I posted an example of what I'm talking about. If you need to store the formatted bits, you can use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: Ah now you are very close. But I want the updated values to show up inside that same textbox that you are typing in. Basically, it changes the words you type, as you type them